# Load integral sign from eulervm

Tags: math-mode, symbols, math-operators

I want to write a book for university and I want to have the "german" integral symbol in it. I tried using `mathabx` and `wasysym` but I don't like them. But I like the integral symbol in `eulervm`.
How do I load this symbol?

I have already tried:

```
\documentclass{article}
\let\int\undefined
\DeclareSymbolFont{largesymbols}{OMX}{eulervm}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\int}{\mathop}{largesymbols}{"52}
\begin{document}
\[ \int \]
\end{document}
```

But that just loads the normal "american" integral symbol.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you redefine the `largesymbols` font, all large operators will be taken from the Euler font. Moreover, the call is wrong:

```
\DeclareSymbolFont{eulargesymbols}{U}{zeuex}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\intop}{\mathop}{eulargesymbols}{"52}
```

Here is the picture (on the right the usual symbol)

[image]

---

How does one discover what should be done? Well, it depends on the font one has to use. Let's make an example: we want some large symbols from the font used by `mathpazo`.

We find in `mathpazo.sty` what font is used:

```
\DeclareSymbolFont{largesymbols}{OMX}{zplm}{m}{n}
```

Thus we just change the symbolic name to something like `pazolargesymbols` and do as the previous case; since the encoding is `OMX`, which is the same normally used for math extension fonts, we know that the integral will be in the same slot as in the usual setting:

```
\DeclareMathSymbol{\intop}{\mathop}{pazolargesymbols}{"52}
```

One can find the standard definition in `fontmath.ltx`.

If the encoding is non standard, as in the case of `eulervm`, we need to check for the slot. However, `eulervm.sty` doesn't redefine `\intop`, so we can be confident that the usual slot is good. It could be different for other symbols.

Note that we have to define `\intop` rather than `\int`, because the latter is defined by LaTeX as

```
\def\int{\intop\nolimits}
```

The `amsmath` package does a different definition of `\int`, but it uses `\intop` for the symbol as well.

Comment: @egreg For the sake of generalizing the procedure, could you explain how to use the large symbols font from `latin modern` for example, or from the `Minion Pro` font?. What exactly needs to be changed in the code from your answer?

Comment: @jrojasqu I've added some notes.