# How to Obtain a Bold Upright Integral Sign?

Tags: symbols, math-operators

Having searched around I couldn't find a package that could produce the following integral sign.

[image]

How do I produce this bold looking vertical symbol? Xe-/LuaTeX are totally fine with me.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$\int_a^b$ 
\end{document}
```

Comment: What size do you want? If you want to center a formula just use `\[\int_{min}^{max} f(x) dx\]` for example.

Comment: Times truetype font

Comment: Yes XeTeX and LuaTeX

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Load integral sign from eulervm](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41892/load-integral-sign-from-eulervm)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With Lua- or XeLaTeX you can use the package `unicode-math` and substitute single symbols easily. Just download any font you like and use it like:

```
% arara: lualatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
\setmathfont[range="222B]{Linux Libertine O} % or any font you like

\begin{document}    
    $\int_{a}^{b}\displaystyle\int_{a}^{b}\int\limits_{a}^{b}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Other [fonts](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/222b/fontsupport.htm) for this case. You might want to replace the other integral signs as well. Linux Libertine covers [U+222B](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/222b/index.htm) to [U+222E](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/222e/index.htm).

```
% arara: lualatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
\setmathfont[range={"222B-"2230}]{Linux Libertine O}

\begin{document}    
    $\int\iint\iiint\oint$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Have to use this in a math environment. Currently using mathptmx but symbols are being produced using CM

Comment: I could not get it to load using 
\DeclareSymbolFont{fnt}{T1}{libertine}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\intop}{\mathop}{fnt}{"222B}`

Comment: Error Limit controls must follow a math operator $\int

Comment: @yolo please see my update.

Comment: Thanks, I am able to produce these symbols but for some odd reason other symbols like \infty or \lambda are not appearing now. Any idea why. Just use the code you just gave me and try a symbol outside the range.

Comment: @yolo Sorry, I did not know that I have to define the default font "Latin Modern Math" as well, when setting some differing range. Now it works.

Answer (score 7):

Employing a variation of my answer at [Integral Sign $\int...$](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/170028/integral-sign-int/170033#170033), I define a new operator `\uint` and show the comparison to `\int` in the MWE below.

This approach takes a traditional `\scriptstyle` integral sign, rotates it 8 degrees, and scales it up to the same vertical extent as a normal integral sign when employed in the current mathstyle.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\uint}{\scalerel*{\rotatebox{8}{$\!\scriptstyle\int\!$}}{\int}}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\parskip 1ex
\begin{document}
\[ 
f=\int_0^t A d\tau =\uint_0^t A d\tau
\]
\centering
\(
f=\int_0^t A d\tau =\uint_0^t A d\tau
\)\par
\(
\scriptstyle f=\int A d\tau =\uint A d\tau
\)\par
\(
\scriptscriptstyle f=\int A d\tau =\uint A d\tau
\)
\end{document}
```

[image]

If the integral sign is perceived as just a bit too bold, then the we can scale a `\textstyle` integral sign instead:

```
\DeclareMathOperator*{\uint}{\scalerel*{\rotatebox{8}{$\!\textstyle\int\!$}}{\int}}
```

[image]