# How do I type out this integral?

Tags: math-mode, symbols

I am fairly new to TeX, and I am currently using TexStudio.

I am wondering how  I can exactly replicate the typesetting of the integral below, including the font and the upright integral sign? What packages, what font? 
[image]

Thank you.

Comment: Did you mean to delete the screenshot?

Comment: @satokun Please reupload your screenshot. This question is now pretty much worthless for the community.

Comment: Saying that you prefer egreg's solution can not be a good reason for deleting the initial screenshot. As @Holene has pointed out, the entire query is worthless -- and should probably be deleted -- without that screenshot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seems quite similar to `newtxmath` with the `upint` option:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage[upint]{newtxmath}

\newcommand{\diff}{\mathop{}\!d}

\begin{document}

\[
\int x^n\diff x
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm always puzzled when I see an accepted answer with 0 score.  Time to change that :)

Answer (score 4):

Basic math is included in LaTeX without any additional packages. I would write:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\[ \int x^n\, \mathrm{d}x \]

\end{document}
```

If you just type `dx` instead of `\mathrm{d}x`, the `d` will be put in italic (like in your example).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But this produces a slanted integral sign. How can I make it straight?

Comment: In this case, check the following question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/222243/how-to-obtain-a-bold-upright-integral-sign

Comment: `\text` is completely wrong here. There are so many people misusing `\text` in this way. Here `\mathrm` should be used, not `\text`. `\text` has one and one use only (except for `siunitx` which "misuses" it a bit): textual comments in displayed math. This is clearly not such a case.

Comment: @daleif Thanks for pointing it out, you are completely right. I changed my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks again. I somehow missed the comma when reading the comment. Either my eyes are too bad or my screen is too small :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you are new to \LaTeX. Here is your answer. I am also teaching you how to specify the limits of integration:

```
$\displaystyle \int_a^b x^n \, dx$
```

The `\,` directive inserts a thinspace between the integrand and the variable of integration; this is commonly done in (good) math typography.

If you need an expression *without* limits of integration:

```
$\displaystyle \int x^n \, dx$
```

Comment: I've taken the liberty of streamlining your answer a bit; feel free to revert if you disagree with the changes.