# Optidef constraint name not aligned properly

Tags: math-mode, spacing, macros, equations, optidef

I have tried to follow optidef.tex to make the constraint names aligned. Here is the code:

```
\begin{mini*}|s|
    {\substack{\mathbf{x},\mathbf{u}}}{J = \phi\left(\mathbf{x}\left(t_f\right),t_f\right) + \int_{t_0}^{t_f}\mathcal{L}\left(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{u},t\right)dt}{}{}
            \addConstraint{\dot{\mathbf{x}} =}{\mathbf{f}\left(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{u},t\right)}
            \addConstraint{\mathbf{x}\left(0\right)}{= \mathbf{x}_0,}{\quad\text{(Initial condition)}}
            \addConstraint{\Psi\left(\mathbf{x}_f,t_f\right) }{= 0,} {\quad\text{(Terminal constraints)}}
    \end{mini*}
```

And here is the corresponding output that is circled:
[image]

Can some explain what is going on? I am writing this out in TeXpad.

Comment: You just need to move the position of the `=` sign in 
`\addConstraint{\dot{\mathbf{x}} =}{\mathbf{f}\left(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{u},t\right)}`
to become `\addConstraint{\dot{\mathbf{x}}}{ =\mathbf{f}\left(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{u},t\right)}`.

Comment: I tried, but it didn’t work

Comment: Do the provided answers solve your problem? If yes, then consider upvoting and accepting one of the answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll be happy to remove this post. According to what I find, you just need to move the position of the `=` sign in

```
\addConstraint{\dot{\mathbf{x}} =}{\mathbf{f}\left(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{u},t\right)}
```

to become

```
\addConstraint{\dot{\mathbf{x}}}{ =\mathbf{f}\left(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{u},t\right)}
```

Full example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{optidef}
\begin{document}
\begin{mini*}|s|
    {\substack{\mathbf{x},\mathbf{u}}}{J = \phi\left(\mathbf{x}\left(t_f\right),t_f\right) + \int_{t_0}^{t_f}\mathcal{L}\left(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{u},t\right)dt}{}{}
            \addConstraint{\dot{\mathbf{x}} }{=\mathbf{f}\left(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{u},t\right)}
            \addConstraint{\mathbf{x}\left(0\right)}{= \mathbf{x}_0,}{\quad\text{(Initial condition)}}
            \addConstraint{\Psi\left(\mathbf{x}_f,t_f\right) }{= 0,} {\quad\text{(Terminal constraints)}}
\end{mini*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

There are many things one could improve like the `\substack` or the differential `d`.

Comment: +1. Another way in which the code could be improved is by omitting all `\left` and `\right` auto-sizing instructions, the more so as these instructions don't do anything except insert undesirable horizontal whitespace.

Comment: I have a strong feeling that Texpad is being very glitchy. What software did you use, Schrödinger’s cat?

Comment: @Superman `pdflatex`.

Comment: @Mico Sure. I was just writing this because I was told my suggestion would not work. (If I was you I would make the differential d's upright in your answer. This seems to be some physics problem. Even though there are some claims that some mathematicians would not use upright upright d's (I know and interact with many, and anyone consciously typing uses an upright d), in physics it is unambiguous.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat I looked more into Texpad, I think it uses TexpadTex instead of pdflatex

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Oh by the way, I figured out what happened; in the terminal constraints line, I put a space between the braces (the right one containing the RHS and the left one containing the Terminal constraints description). Removing the space causes the output to become properly aligned

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat - Thanks for the suggestion to render the `d` (differential) operators in upright math mode. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: @Mico I had upvoted it already...

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat - +++ :-)

Answer (score 2):

Just for reference, here's a solution which does *not* employ the `optidef` package. Instead, it employs 1 `align*` environment (for the 4 "outer" blocks) and 1 `aligned` environment (for the group of 3 "inner" blocks which, together, make up the final "outer" block).  `align*` and `aligned` are both provided by the `amsmath` package.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,bm}
\newcommand{\diff}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}} % see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/385862/5001
\newcommand\tf{t\mkern-1.5mu_f} % snug up the subscript-f to the t

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
&\text{PM: } \textstyle 
  J=\phi(\mathbf{x}(\tf),\tf)
  +\int_{t_0}^{\tf}\!\mathcal{L}(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{u},t)\diff t \\
&\text{General Problem: } \textstyle 
  \min J=\phi(\mathbf{x}(\tf))
  +\int_{t_0}^{\tf}\! \mathcal{L}(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{u},t)\diff t\\
&{\min_{\mathbf{x},\mathbf{u}}} \quad
  J=\phi(\mathbf{x}(\tf),\tf)
  +\int_{t_0}^{\tf} \!\! \mathcal{L}(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{u},t)\diff t \\
&\text{s.t.} \quad
  \begin{aligned}[t]
  \dot{\mathbf{x}} &= \mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{u},t) \\
  \mathbf{x}(0) &= x_0 \qquad\text{(Initial condition)}\\
  \bm{\Psi}(\mathbf{x}_f,\tf) &= 0_{\phantom{0}} \qquad{\text{(Terminal constraint)}}
  \end{aligned}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I cannot reproduce the output you get with your code.

Besides moving the `=` to the second argument to `\AddConstraint`, as suggested in [another answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/527884/4427), I propose a different setting, with constraints left aligned, which seems better to me.

Also I removed all `\left`/`\right` pairs, which do nothing besides adding unwanted space. A `\,` before `dt` is necessary, instead. Whether you want an upright “d” or not is *your* choice: conform to what is the usage in your field (or to your personal preference).

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,optidef}

\begin{document}

\subsection*{Original}

\begin{mini*}|s|
    {\substack{\mathbf{x},\mathbf{u}}}{J = \phi\left(\mathbf{x}\left(t_f\right),t_f\right) + \int_{t_0}^{t_f}\mathcal{L}\left(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{u},t\right)dt}{}{}
            \addConstraint{\dot{\mathbf{x}} =}{\mathbf{f}\left(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{u},t\right)}
            \addConstraint{\mathbf{x}\left(0\right)}{= \mathbf{x}_0,}{\quad\text{(Initial condition)}}
            \addConstraint{\Psi\left(\mathbf{x}_f,t_f\right) }{= 0,} {\quad\text{(Terminal constraints)}}
    \end{mini*}

\subsection*{Left alignment}

\begin{mini*}|s|
  {\scriptstyle\mathbf{x},\mathbf{u}}
  {J = \phi(\mathbf{x}(t_f),t_f) + \int_{t_0}^{t_f}\mathcal{L}(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{u},t)\,dt}{}{}
\addConstraint{}{\dot{\mathbf{x}}=\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{u},t)}{}
\addConstraint{}{\mathbf{x}(0)= \mathbf{x}_0,}{\quad\text{(Initial condition)}}
\addConstraint{}{\Psi(\mathbf{x}_f,t_f)= 0,}{\quad\text{(Terminal constraints)}}
\end{mini*}

\subsection*{Alignment at equals signs}

\begin{mini*}|s|
  {\scriptstyle\mathbf{x},\mathbf{u}}
  {J = \phi(\mathbf{x}(t_f),t_f) + \int_{t_0}^{t_f}\mathcal{L}(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{u},t)\,dt}{}{}
\addConstraint{\dot{\mathbf{x}}}{=\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{u},t)}{}
\addConstraint{\mathbf{x}(0)}{= \mathbf{x}_0,}{\quad\text{(Initial condition)}}
\addConstraint{\Psi(\mathbf{x}_f,t_f)}{= 0,}{\quad\text{(Terminal constraints)}}
\end{mini*}

\end{document}
```

In my opinion, `optidef` *should* have an option to make the subscript variables in script size instead of normal size. I opted for a simpler `\scriptstyle` declaration in place of the more complicated `\substack`.

[image]

As a further simplification for inputting your formulas, I suggest to add something like

```
\newcommand{\vectorvariable}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}
\newcommand{\vf}{\vectorvariable{f}}
\newcommand{\vu}{\vectorvariable{u}}
\newcommand{\vx}{\vectorvariable{x}}
```

so, for instance, the first constraint would become

```
\addConstraint{}{\dot{\vx}}=\vf(\vx,\vu,t)}{}
```

In case a reviewer tells you that vector variables should be in bold italic, you'll just have to add

```
\usepackage{bm}
```

and change a single line in your code, namely

```
\newcommand{\vectorvariable}[1]{\bm{#1}}
```

After this, running LaTeX on your document would yield

[image]

(or the other layout, according to the one you prefer, of course). Similarly, adding

```latex
\newcommand{\diff}{\mathop{}\!d}
```

and typing `\diff t` when you want the differential, will allow you to cope with fussy reviewers or supervisors requiring an upright “d” by just changing a single line of code. Note that if you go this way, the `\,` in front of the differential in integrals should be removed.