# Integral sign from Txfonts

Tags: integral, txfonts

There were several questions for this, but none answer my doubt completely. My initial code is as follows (compiled with pdflatex):

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,notitlepage,onecolumn,oneside]{mwart}
\usepackage[top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, left=2cm, right=2cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{upgreek} 
\usepackage[polish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[OT4]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{xcolor}
```

I followed the advice to create a new symbol:

```
\DeclareMathOperator*{\uint}{\scalerel*{\rotatebox{8}{$\!\textstyle\int\!$}}{\int}}
```

but it's still worse than one observed in Txfonts

http://piotrkosoft.net/pub/mirrors/CTAN/fonts/txfonts/doc/txfontsdocA4.pdf

Is it possible to use this single integral sign? Many thanks in advance.

Previous posts:
[Integral Sign $\int...$](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/170028/integral-sign-int)
[How to Obtain a Bold Upright Integral Sign?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/222243/how-to-obtain-a-bold-upright-integral-sign)

Answer (score 2):

To begin with, use `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`. The standard fonts have covered Polish for more than twenty years and the `OT4` kludges are no longer needed.

If you want to use the integral signs from the TX fonts (I'm not sure why), you can define a new symbol font.

```latex
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,notitlepage,onecolumn,oneside]{mwart}
\usepackage[top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, left=2cm, right=2cm]{geometry} 

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % unneeded with recent LaTeX
\usepackage[polish]{babel}

%\usepackage{amsfonts} % unneeded with amssymb
\let\lll\relax % to avoid the error
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}

% not needed for the example
%\usepackage{upgreek} 
%\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{color} % unneeded with xcolor
%\usepackage{xcolor}

\DeclareSymbolFont{TXlargesymbols}{OMX}{txex}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{TXlargesymbols}{bold}{OMX}{txex}{bx}{n}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{OMX}{txex}{m}{n}

\DeclareMathSymbol{\intop}{\mathop}{TXlargesymbols}{"52}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\ointop}{\mathop}{TXlargesymbols}{"48}

\begin{document}

\[
\int_1^x\frac{1}{t}\,dt + \oint_\gamma \frac{1}{z}\,dz+\iint+\iiint
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks, works a like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Although you’re using the legacy tools with seven-bit(!) fonts, in the modern toolchain, you can do this with the `range=` option of `\setmathfont`.  For example, to use the integral symbols from STIX Two Math in `unicode-math`:

```
\setmathfont[range={"222B-"2233,"2A0B-"2A1C},Scale=MatchUppercase]{XITS Math}
```

You can add the `StylisticSet=8` option to get the alternative upright integrals.